# How to achieve effect used on http://www.googleventures.com/?

Tags: jquery, html, css, web, scroll

I need some help with recreating the effect found on http://www.googleventures.com/  I am wanting to make a header and content slider on my website that stays in place as the rest of the page scrolls over it. How can I do this? Any help would be much appreciated! I though it might be possible with parallax, but I cannot figure out how to do it...Please help!

Comment: Actually, this can be done purely with css.  You just need a fixed background div with a relative foreground which has a margin-top value large enough to show the background div

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do that with http://html9responsiveboilerstrapjs.com/

Comment: Right, all kidding aside, this is a very simple css trick.

Comment: In all due respect, irrespective of the other "comments" offered, the effect described by reference in the question subject is perhaps less than permanent. Saying "I want this effect, show me" usually barely rises to a valid question on SO. Maybe one of the boo-chorus wants to elaborate on their genius, but I vote to close as "Not constructive". Sorry. And welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go, http://jsfiddle.net/xbXhD/1/

The top div can have links etc. as well like on Google Ventures, not just an image. You get the idea :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do mark the answer as accepted if you found it useful. And read Jared's comment on top. Also, before asking on SO you should put in your own effort first. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to use `margin-top`. See this simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/lbstr/QE3Qh/11/

**Allow me to explain what I've done in the fiddle:**

You have two divs, `#fixed` and `#content`.

`#fixed` has a nav menu and as the name implies is fixed. `z-index: 1` makes sure it stays under the `#content` div. Here is the css:

```
#fixed { position: fixed; top: 0; padding: 200px 0;z-index: 1 }
```

`#content` has a big `margin-top` that allows us to see `#fixed` when scrolled to the top of hte page. It has a higher `z-index` so that it will show up on top of `#fixed` when scrolled. Don't forget to add some `position`, otherwise `z-index` means nothing. Here is that css:

```
#content { margin-top: 400px; background-color: white; z-index: 2; position: relative; }​
```

Comment: What you included in the answer (not in the link) doesn't actually amount to documenting your effect. It does work, but please document it in your answer. `:)`

Comment: I've updated my answer with a bit of explanation. It is working fine for me in Chrome and FF.

Comment: I agree. Maybe that was before my edit. I didn't have much of an explanation at that point...

Comment: Neither does the "upvoted" answer, which I suspect was upvoted by said downvoter.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps - http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/

You could achieve parallax via css as well

Comment: I think that is overkill for this situation, but I dont' think its worth a downvote, so I'm upping you back to 0.